# Why doesn't this bash script read from stdin but rather terminates?

Tags: bash, pipe

I am writing a very simple drop-in replacement for zsh-select to use in my bash scripts. This is part of my `.bashrc`

```bash
bash-select(){
  declare -a arr;
  while read l; do
    arr+=( "$l" );
  done
  PS3="$1: ";
  if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then PS3="Choose: "; fi
  select sel in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo $sel;
    break;
  done
}
```

Running it, however, `select` does not query `stdin` for a value but instantly terminates with exit code 1.
`echo`s at the end of the script (after the select statement) get printed nevertheless.
It seems as if `stdin` is not connected to `select` and I suspect it might be the way in which i read the options from the pipe. (Please correct me, if this is wrong.)

How could I change/fix the code to make it work like this?

```
$> ls | bash-select
1) file1
2) file2
3) file3
Choose: 3
file3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `select` does not query stdin for a value but instantly terminates with exit code 1

It *does* query stdin but gets EOF because your while loop consumes all input. Try redirecting its input from the terminal:

```
  select sel in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo $sel;
    break;
  done </dev/tty
```

Comment: @FabianSchneider No it doesn't get closed, but that doesn't matter. `echo $sel` writes to stdout and would still work if stdin were closed.